# Highlighting Highcharts series from a remote element

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to figure out how to highlight a line (series) in Highcharts from an element that's  not related to the Chart object in any way.

I went through the documentation, and don't really see a way of achieving this. I can get into the series elements using the `series.get(id)`.

Seems like there are no methods that can be helpful - http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#series-object

Any ideas if that's even possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a lot of digging and testing, I've managed to get this working - still not sure if this is the best way (probably not).

`Chart.series.get(someId).graph.attr('stroke-width', '5')`

Unfortunately, this is just getting into the actual DOM element and changing the value of the property of a single element, so if you need to change the stroke width, and the styles of the markers on this line, you'd have to loop through all elements, and apply changes manually.

**UPDATE: Ok, there's a better way**

But this is using the private API, so if the library changes thins, your code will not work:

`Chart.series.get(someId).onMouseOver()` and `Chart.series.get(someId).onMouseOut()`.

This actually fires the defined hover-state.

Comment: I've not been able to get it to work but also take a look at `series.setState()` https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series.html#setState .

I ended up using `series.hide()` and `series.show()` to toggle the series on click.