# Problematically highlight(hover) a serie ,highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Say I have a list of a serie name outside the plot, when I hover at one of them I want to set one of the series highlighted(hovered).

This is **AFTER** the the plot is rendered.

How can I achieve this(I am also using jQuery)

Comment: See this: [Highlighting Highcharts series from a remote element](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8810092/2732991)

Comment: @Ondkloss, I can't find the Chart object? How can I get that?

Comment: `var chart = $('#container').highcharts();`

Comment: @Ondkloss , this indeed returns something but it is not a object contains sereis property

Comment: You have to make that var after the chart has been created.

Comment: For me above solution works perfectly fine.. demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L3guwfck/1/

Comment: @PawełFus, what if my series does not have id, only have name?

Comment: Then set ID to be the same as name? ;) There is many other options, like instead of using name, use index of the series (`chart.series[index]`).

Comment: @PawełFus, I am not ready to re-construct my series array, now I am using $.each all the series and compare the name, I not sure if there are any faster way

Answer (score 0):

Thank for @Paweł Fus's help.
Finally, I use below way to solve this problem. Since I do not have id in my series array, I use `$each()` to compare the name

```
        var chart = $plotResult.highcharts();//get the chart object

        var highlightSerieCallback = function(e){//mouse in callback
            var seriesName = $(this).find(':first-child').text();
            console.log('serieName hightLight',seriesName);
            $.each(chart.series, function(i, s) {
                if(s.name == seriesName){
                    s.onMouseOver();
                    return false;//break the each
                }

            });
        };

        var disHighlightSerieCallback = function(e){//mouse leave callback
            var seriesName = $(this).find(':first-child').text();
            console.log('serieName DisHightLight',seriesName);
            $.each(chart.series, function(i, s) {
                if(s.name == seriesName){
                    s.onMouseOut();
                    return false;//break the each
                }
            });
    };

        $sumAndAvgResultWrap.find('tr:not(:first-child)').hover(highlightSerieCallback,disHighlightSerieCallback);//bind the callback
```